# Html disconnected nodes

Tags: html

[This](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#ordering-of-disconnected-nodes-within-a-jquery-set) jquery migration guide mentions disconnected nodes. What is the meaning of a disconnected node in html ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means a DOM node that is not "connected" to the actual document.

In other words, a DOM node or subtree that you created or parsed, but did not append to the document itself.

Comment: Would an absolutely positioned element qualify as being a disconnected node as that does not actually reside in the DOM hierarchy but somewhere on the document ?

Comment: @ShaggyInjun - No, and you're pretty confused. Absolute positioned elements are taken out of the [*flow*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow), but no positioning, nor any other styling, removes an element from the *DOM document*.